# How to do Testcases for a specification document?

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, testcase, documentation, test-data

I have always done these very simple test cases so I am actually very lost and got overwhelmed when I got this assignment where I should do test cases from a functional design specification document. Of course you have your introduction and purpose then there are different section and the section themselves have sub-sections (3.1, 3.2). One of the functions being example search, add, edit and remove in shopping cart on the website and other for an app. And then there is attachment with pictures of the prototypes showing these functions, diagrams, additional/subblementary specification, UI etc. It's a lot!

I don't really know how to tackle these. If I were to write for test cases for each subsection, I think there would be alot. How do I need to think and go about solving this? This might actually sound easy to many of you but I just started with testing (7 month ago). This is really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Test cases can be a helpful way to ensure that a product meets its functional requirements and behaves as intended. Here are a few steps you can take to create test cases for a specification document:

- Read and understand the specification document thoroughly. Make sure
  you have a clear understanding of the product's intended behavior and
  features.
- Identify the different sections and sub-sections of the specification
  document. Consider creating a test case for each section or
  sub-section to ensure that all parts of the product are thoroughly
  tested.
- For each section or sub-section, think about the different scenarios
  that the product might encounter. For example, if you are testing the
  shopping cart feature, you might consider test cases for adding items
  to the cart, removing items from the cart, and updating the quantity
  of items in the cart.
- Use the prototypes and diagrams in the attachment to help you
  visualize the product's behavior. This can be especially helpful if
  the specification document does not include detailed descriptions of
  the product's behavior.
- Write a test case for each scenario you identified in step 3. A test
  case should include a clear description of the steps to be followed
  to test the feature, as well as the expected result.
- Review your test cases to make sure they are clear, complete, and
  test all relevant aspects of the product's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Testing a functional design layout specification file can appear overwhelming, however it's far a essential method for making sure that the software program product being advanced meets the favoured necessities.  Here are the stairs you could comply with to create check instances for a specification file:

1. Ensure which you have an excellent information of the file and its numerous sections, which includes the purpose, features, and necessities.
2. Look for the precise necessities withinside the file and create a listing of all of the functions and features that want to be examined.
3. Based at the necessities, decide the targets of every check case and what the predicted final results is.
4. Divide the necessities into smaller, viable portions that may be examined individually. This will assist you to create extra centered and complete check instances.
5. Write the check instances in a clean and concise manner, which includes the check steps, predicted results, and any preconditions that want to be met.
6. Review the check instances to make certain that they may be complete, accurate, and they cowl all of the necessities certain withinside the file.
7. Based at the criticality of the necessities, prioritize the check instances in order that the maximum essential ones are examined first.
8. Run the check instances and file the results. If any insects or defects are found, document them and paintings with the improvement group to clear up them.
9. Regularly overview and replace the check instances as adjustments are made to the specification file.

Answer (score 0):

As an outsourced software testing organization, writing a test case w.r.t. FIGMA or Design Steps for both Web and Mobile apps requires a lot of brainstorming.
Hence as per my experience and recommendation:

1. Create single test case each for functional test cases i.e. for major functionalities/application workflows. However, when you create a TestRun --> at that point select the test cases in both test runs say for Web and iOS as the core application functionality is same.
2. Additionally for UI test cases, create one test case each for individual screens and attach the screenshots in a TestRun for reference so that can be viewed while you are executing the tests.

Comment: Thank you! so its fine doing testcases for each then! But how would I do a testrun when the app and website in the document does not exist?